# Should board/residential lease be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

Are the words "board lease" or "residential lease" capitalized in a sentence?  I am a secretary for a school board (is that capitalized?? ha) and these phrases are very frequent.  Thank you.

Comment: If they're frequent, they needn't be capitalized. The point of capitalizing proper nouns is to make them stand out; but that's just distracting with phrases that pop up in their normal context.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, since those are legal terms, they would be defined and then capitalized -- at least they would be by lawyers.  As an example: ". . . the residential lease for the property commonly known as 'X' (hereinafter 'Lease' or 'Residential Lease').".

For the next usage you would simply write (e.g.): "For these reasons, the security deposit provisions of the Lease are inapplicable." or "For these reasons, the security deposit provisions of the Residential Lease are inapplicable.".